# Get metadata info without downloading the complete file

Tags: python-2.7, libtorrent

As I read the different posts here and [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html) documentation, I know (as documented), I have to download the torrent file in order to get the metadata. but how the uTorrent App works, when I just start downloading, I get the metadata within a second then after getting the metadata, I can pause downloading. So, it doesn't restrict me to download a complete file in order to return metadata.

So, is there a way to get metadata without downloading the complete file

Answer (score 0):

libtorrent's [`metadata_received_alert`](http://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Alerts.html#metadata-received-alert) is what you want. This will be sent once the metadata finishes downloading. Do make sure that youre receiving status notifications though.